# How to inject these four $scope, $http, $q, $location in a single inject statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, dependency-injection

I want to try inject this all in single inject statement in typescript but it show error in last one injecting. here $location inject is undefined, if I replace last (4th) with $scope (swap $scope to $location) than $scope is undefined show in chrome Developer tool debugging time.

typescript code:

```
module app.common {
'use strict';    
export class StatisticalPortalService {
static $inject = ['$scope', '$q', '$http', '$location'];
constructor(private $scope,
                    private $q,
                    private $http,
                    private $location) {
```

compile javascript code:

```
var app;
(function (app) {
    var common;
    (function (common) {
        'use strict';
        var StatisticalPortalService = (function () {
            function StatisticalPortalService($scope, $q, $http, $location) {
                var _this = this;
                this.$scope = $scope;
                this.$q = $q;
                this.$http = $http;
                this.$location = $location;
```

Comment: `"error in last one injecting"` What exactly error? unpr?

Comment: Is there `StatisticalPortalService.$inject = [...]` statement in compiled js?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing should work fine.  I notice there's an extra comma in your $inject array. Could that be it or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specified type of four $:

```
module app.common {
'use strict';    
export class StatisticalPortalService {
static $inject = ['$scope', '$q', '$http', '$location'];
constructor(private $scope:any,
                    private $q:ng.IQService,
                    private $http:ng.IHttpService,
                    private $location:ng.ILocationService) {
```